# Disable autocomplete in login form

Tags: autocomplete, cross-browser

What is a cross browser way to disable autocomplete for input fields in a login form ?

I have already used autocomplete='off' which is not working in chrome for example

Thank

Answer (score 0):

So Chrome doesn't care about "autocomplete" anymore so you have to trick it into saving empty fields or nothing at all. Here is one possible solution:

```
<form action='/login' class='login-form' autocomplete='off'>
  Email:
  <input type='email' name='email-email-input'>
  <input type='hidden' name='email'>

  Password:
  <input type='password' name='password-input'>
  <input type='hidden' name='password'>
</form>
<script>
  $('.login-form').on('submit', function() {
    $('[name="email"]').val($('[name="email-input"]').val());
    $('[name="email-input"]').val('');
    $('[name="password"]').val($('[name="password-input"]').val());
    $('[name="password-input"]').val('');
  });
</script>
```